# 415 Unsuppoted Media Type when I try send JSON to Spring MVC Controller

Tags: java, jquery, json, spring, controller

When I try send JSON to Spring MVC Controller I got:

```
POST http://localhost:8084/springAndHibernate/greet 415 (Unsupported Media Type)
```

Here is declaration of method which should ,,catch" JSON:

```
@RequestMapping(headers ={"Accept=application/json"},value="/greet")
public String greetUser(@RequestBody Logins newLogin){
```

I thought it should map JSON to class Logins.java, which is here:

```
package newpackage;

public class Logins  implements java.io.Serializable {


 private int id;
 private String login;
 private String password;

public Logins() {
}


public Logins(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public Logins(int id, String login, String password) {
   this.id = id;
   this.login = login;
   this.password = password;
}

public int getId() {
    return this.id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getLogin() {
    return this.login;
}

public void setLogin(String login) {
    this.login = login;
}
public String getPassword() {
    return this.password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}
```

}

I send POST with jQuery ajax() method in this way:

```
 function onGreetingButtonClicked(e){

                var contextPath='<%=request.getContextPath()%>';
                jsonData = {
                    id: 0,
                    login: $("#loginInput").val(),
                    password: $("#passwordInput").val()
                };
                console.log(JSON.stringify(jsonData));
                console.log((contextPath + "/greet").toString());
                urlAddress = (contextPath + "/greet")

                $.ajax({type: "POST",
                    url: urlAddress, 
                    data: JSON.stringify(jsonData),
                    success: onSuccess,
                    contentType: "application/jsonp; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: null,
                    traditional: true});
                e.preventDefault();              
            }
            function onSuccess(data){
                alert(data);
            }
```

When I delete

```
@RequestBody
```

from method there is no mistakes, but then I get Logins object with null as a fields value.

I would be very happy if anybody want to help me,
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Start by setting your log level to DEBUG. Spring should tell you what went wrong.

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis , how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on various other postings, you should be setting the contentType to `"application/javascript"`.

I've also seen suggestions to use `"application/json"`, but looking at the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP), it is clear that JSON-P is actually not valid JSON, so that MIME-type is incorrect, even though some browsers apparently know how to deal with the mistake.

At any rate, `"application/jsonp"` is incorrect because it is not a registered MIME-type.